# Android number of exact downloads

Tags: java, php, android, firefox-addon, google-play

From what I know, you can't get the exact number of users which downloaded your app, unless you're connected to your Google plus account. Is that true? (I haven't yet got a google play (android market) account, my app isn't yet up on the market, so i just wanna make sure i'm saying valid things here.)

Is there any way i could programmatically get the number of downloads, preferably in real time?

From what I've found, there isn't an API for the market which let's me do this. So how can this be accomplished?

I need to take that value and in real time update a graph on my website and blog.

Can anyone come up with a workaround for this? One thing i was thinking of was: to either make a Firefox extension which on my home machine, automatically connects to my Google plus account, takes the required value and updates the page via ftp or something, or instead of Firefox extension i could use PHP locally to do the parsing and whatnot. But i'd need to keep my home machine always on, which i don't really want to.

Any other ideas? I really need that exact value, and i need it to be automated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user downloads the app, you could have it do a callback to a script on your site that does a tally for you. The app should, obviously, only call this on the first run (but, depending on how you implemented it, would probably be called on each refresh of the app's cache/data). If you don't have a service that needs registration, you could have it done in the background.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't think of this solution. This might even work in real time, and i also already know how to check for the first run of an app. :D Awesome, will wait for some other ideas though, but this one sounds promising.

Comment: Hmm ... but here's a stupid question probably: so you're saying i could call a JS script from my android app? Any suggestions on how that is done?

Comment: Not necessarily a Javascript call. You can just have a hook. I'm not an Android developer, so I'm not 100% sure how you could do it. From what I read (rather quickly, so it my be inaccurate), you can use the built-in HTTP library to make a request. So, just have it as a script. Something like http://yoursite.com/android-download-counter and just process whatever request data comes from it. (Just make sure you handle timeouts and such appropriately so your app doesn't crash or get hung up on it. ;)

Comment: How would i limit the requests only from my app? 'cause anyone could make a quick script and start requesting, and ruin my counter.

Comment: You could generate a verification token in your app and verify it server-side. For instance, use a hashing algo like md5 and string together the current UNIX timestamp and a token string that only you know. Send that verification token and timestamp to the script, hash the timestamp with the token string server-side and, if it matches, you have a winner. Otherwise, just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible by default. The only figures that do exist are only updated daily at most.

You would need to devise your own way to count downloads such as requiring your users to register on your own service.

Comment: But when the update occurs, daily or whatever, it displays an exact number of downloads from that day no? Not an interval, or some other approximate value.

Comment: Also, my app won't be free, so Google will display each user's information on my page. Will that data be updated daily as well? :(

Comment: It may or may not have been an exact count at the time it was updated but nobody knows when the count was taken so it will never be a 100% correct count. Also it depends what you consider a download as the same user can install and uninstall an app many times on various different devices. E.g I have 6 android devices. If u buy an app I can install it on all 6 but only pay once.